# Get a Warning message box

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am working on a project and need help with VBA. As shown in the table attached, what I need is VBA code that would alert me if any the value in column B (SBO) is FALSE. I tried the code below but it is not giving me desired result so I would appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks!

```
Sub SBO_Lookup()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
If Sheet1.Range("B:B").Value = "FALSE" Then
MsgBox "False SBO detected"
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Range.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method:

```
If Sheet1.Range("B:B").Find("False") Is Not Nothing Then
    MsgBox "False SBO Detected"
End If
```

You could also use [`WorksheetFunction.CountIf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif) method:

```
If WorksheetFunction.Countif(Sheet1.Range("B:B"), "FALSE") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "False SBO Detected"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
If [match(false,b:b,0)] Then MsgBox "False SBO detected"
```